# ER modelling tool for Snowflake

Tags: sql, data-modeling, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, warehouse

From snowflake documentation it seems that there is an ER application that will allow connecting to the dwh to create diagrams - https://www.snowflake.com/blog/support-multiple-data-modeling-approaches-with-snowflake/.

Does anyone know what tool is used in the article?
Can you recommend alternative ER tool for modelling purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume that there are several tools that will connect to Snowflake and allow you to edit models of its schemas.

The tool used in [the article](https://www.snowflake.com/blog/support-multiple-data-modeling-approaches-with-snowflake/) looks like [Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/datamodeler.html).
Look at the Wikipedia chart: [Comparison of data modeling tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data_modeling_tools) for alternatives.

Also please remember that [constraints in Snowflake](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/constraints.html) (references, indices) are soft - not enforced - but that doesn't matter and works fine with Entity Relationship Modeling.

Answer (score 0):

Another tool with CI/CD tools I came accross:

https://sqldbm.com/Home/

Answer (score 0):

A tool that I developed: https://www.dev4snow.com/

You can do that and much more with it -it's also an IDE.

Diego.